# What are some lesser-known sustainable technologies suitable for a solarpunk civilization?

Tags: society, technology

I am thinking about things like gravity fed ropeways and trompe powered compressed air.  What other options have been largely forgotten by modern history?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello Chris, welcome to Worldbuilding. This question violates a number of this site's rules (see [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]). Specifically (a) Questions are expected to be specific with a reasonable possibility of one best answer, (b) Questions may not be open-ended. (c) Questions are required to describe conditions, expectations, limitations, and restrictions so answers can be scoped. (d) This is a classical brainstorming question which the [help/on-topic] specifically states is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: What's the tech level for materials and such? Are solar balloons in play?

Comment: Solar balloons are most definitely of interest.  What kind of altitude were you thinking? Just above the weather systems or way up in the stratosphere like JP Aerospace?  What kind of materials for construction and what kind of buoyancy?

Answer (score 4):

Most water-related technology fits this category. Hydraulic machines, hydropower plants, and a transportation system based on canals and boats rather than streets and cars, to name a few.

Hydraulic robots, for example, would only require water to operate, rather than electricity or being wound up, which would allow them to be used without them losing power being as much of a concern. You could consider having your civilization use more efficient versions of water wheels as an energy source, rather than damming up an entire river for a hydropower plant, to limit the impact your civilization has on the its environment. A canal system means no emissions from cars, and likely means group public transport is a lot more common, because everyone having their own boat would get the canals extremely crowded, to extent where the environment might be harmed, which is what it sounds like your civilization is trying to avoid.

Basically, look into water-based technology and energy sources. It's less commonly used in futuristic stories and has a lot of potential.

Comment: Solar steam engines (Stationary) were seriously considered and demonstrated. However coal was just too convenient and cheap.

Answer (score 3):

A reprint of an article about solar powered steam engine can be found [here](https://www.motherearthnews.com/sustainable-living/green-transportation/solar-powered-steam-engine-zmaz75ndzgoe/).  The article describes an 1870s version. But solar concentration for high temperatures was used in Europe much earlier for high temperature furnaces for exploring how to make porcelains in the 1700s. An 1866 solar engine is shown below.

[image: Augustin Mouchot’s Largest Sun Machine]

There were attempts to make commercial scale steam plants but the convenience of coal and gas and their economics won out. A stationary engine would allow you to build factories for textiles or pump water etc.

Looking to the future there are also a lot of efforts to split water using sun light directly without having to make electricity to do electrolysis. That is also something that could be discovered much earlier in a solar energy based society.

I bring that up because sort of energy storage is probably necessary for any solar powered society. I wasn’t sure if electricity was part of your world. Pumping water to higher elevations is probably the easiest to implement, but storing hydrogen or ammonia or even methane that is made using solar power is a possible route.  Hydrogen is the cleanest fuel but hard to store and flammable.

Answer (score 1):

**Biofuel**

[image: growing at sea]

https://www.forbes.com/sites/nishandegnarain/2020/07/29/ocean-crops-is-this-the-next-frontier-for-agriculture/?sh=2bbd9a1b5c95

In your solarpunk world, reed canarygrass has been engineered to be salt tolerant.  Large areas of land where sea level rise has turned the land into brackish swamps are now farmed for this salt tolerant grass - this includes most of Louisana and Bangladesh.  Offshore grass farms exist everywhere and especially near populated areas where the grass serves double duty in remdiating dead zones and absorbing nutrients running off from land farms.

The grass is harvested and burned for energy.  As simple as that.  Canarygrass is already used in that way.  It is also good animal feed.   You could use it as feedstock for [cellulosic ethanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulosic_ethanol) too.

[image: grass pellets]

http://www.gemcopelletmills.com/make-grass-pellets.html